# What are the potential threats of an insecure IPC communication in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, process, vulnerability-assessment

There are two processes on a Windows machine: one is related to user interface (UI) and the other is a backend service running locally. The UI process sends data to the backend service and they mutually communicate with each other using inter-process communication channel.

I want to secure the IPC channel, however, I first want to know the odds of not securing such a channel. In other words, what are the potential threats and what can an attacker achieve by abusing the IPC channel.

One of the examples I could come up with is of "UI impersonation" where  someone can put fake UI process to send fake data. What are the other attacks that can occur?

Comment: What is the IPC channel? They all work differently...

Comment: You are asking your question backwards. Who do you want to protect against? What are their resources? What do you want to protect? When you will have answered those questions, we will be able to give you advice on how to protect your application. But we cannot guess the answer to those questions I asked.

Comment: If you want a very secure method to protect your application against most threats, without giving us more context, you can do this: Do not install any other application on the computer, except from the operating system. Disconnect the computer running the applications from any network (internet and power supply). Place the computer in a bunker, 20 meters deep, isolated in a Faraday cage. Seal the door by welding it. Then cement the access to the door.

Comment: @A.Hersean And give dozens of contractors who build the bunker access to a backdoor!? You always have to remember the risk of insider threats. The bigger the setup, the more insiders there are.

Comment: @forest I guess you will have to do it yourself or kill the contractors afterwards.

Comment: @forest Eventually you will have to permanently terminate any insider, including yourself. This might happen naturally after having exhausted all the dioxygen resources in the bunker.

Comment: Maybe Samurai are the best people for the job.

Comment: @A.Hersean [You forgot the leopard!](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually)